# AWS VPC-based Elasticsearch Service endpoint access

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-vpc

i have carefully followed the steps to setup elasticsearch cluster within a vpc using the aws elasticsearch service. Subnet and security group all setup and ES domain status is green.

But for some reason when i click the endpoint url, it times out. Both for ES and kibana.

Any idea how to access kibana dashboard with my vpc endpoint ?

Comment: Resolved this, apparently you have to proxy your way from your local machine into the aws environment, then you can view the kibana dashboard.

Comment: Can you document how you did this? I'm stuck on the same.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access Kibana from Amazon elasticsearch service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751580/how-to-access-kibana-from-amazon-elasticsearch-service)