# How to control access of AWS Elasticsearch Service and Kibana?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, ip, kibana, amazon-iam

I have an AWS Elasticsearch instance with a Kibana link that I want to share with another person, so that they can access this data from their browser. How can I allow them access?

Answer (score 1):

[This blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-control-access-to-your-amazon-elasticsearch-service-domain/) post does a great job of describing the options available to you for controlling access to Amazon ElasticSearch.

- You can use [identity federation](https://aws.amazon.com/identity/federation/) via [Cognito User Pools](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/cognito-user-identity-pools.html).
- Resource based policy: Explicitly allow access to the cluster for a given IAM user ID in the ElasticSearch policy.
- User based policy: Explicitly grant that IAM user's role access to the ARN of your ES cluster
- Put your ES service behind a proxy with authentication

This SO question/answers go into more depth, with various high quality answers: [How to access Kibana from Amazon elasticsearch service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751580/how-to-access-kibana-from-amazon-elasticsearch-service?rq=1)