# AWS Elasticsearch IAM question to access Kibana via Browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, kibana, amazon-iam, amazon-elasticsearch

I've set up my elasticsearch yml file (deployed via Serverless) as follows:

```
Resources:
CRMSearch:
  Type: "AWS::Elasticsearch::Domain"
  Properties:
    ElasticsearchVersion: "7.10"
    DomainName: "crm-searchdb-${self:custom.stage}"
    ElasticsearchClusterConfig:
      DedicatedMasterEnabled: false
      InstanceCount: "1"
      ZoneAwarenessEnabled: false
      InstanceType: "t3.medium.elasticsearch"
    EBSOptions:
      EBSEnabled: true
      Iops: 0
      VolumeSize: 10
      VolumeType: "gp2"
    AccessPolicies:
      Version: "2012-10-17"
      Statement:
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            AWS: [
              "arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:role/crm-databases-dev-us-east-1-lambdaRole", 
              '#{AWS::AccountId}',
              'arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:user/nicholas',
              'arn:aws:iam::#{AWS::AccountId}:user/daniel'
              ]
          Action: "es:*"
          Resource: "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:#{AWS::AccountId}:domain/crm-searchdb-${self:custom.stage}"
        - Effect: "Allow"
          Principal:
            AWS: [
              "*"
              ]
          Action: "es:*"
          Resource: "arn:aws:es:us-east-1:#{AWS::AccountId}:domain/crm-searchdb-${self:custom.stage}"
    AdvancedOptions: 
      rest.action.multi.allow_explicit_index: 'true'
    AdvancedSecurityOptions:
        Enabled: true
        InternalUserDatabaseEnabled: true
        MasterUserOptions: 
          MasterUserName: admin
          MasterUserPassword: fD343sfdf!3rf
    EncryptionAtRestOptions: 
      Enabled: true
    NodeToNodeEncryptionOptions:
      Enabled: true
    DomainEndpointOptions:
      EnforceHTTPS: true
```

I'm just trying to get access to Kibana via browser. I set up open permission Kibana a few months ago at a previous company, but can't seem to access Kibana via browser no matter what I do. I always get the `{"Message":"User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet"}` error. How do I setup permissions (ideally via yml) to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

> User: anonymous is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpGet

The breakdown of what results in this message is:

1. Your browser fetches Kibana assets / scripts
2. Kibana client-side code running on your browser makes a GET request to your ElasticsearchService domain.
3. Your browser is not a permitted principal and is denied access. The anonymous user from the message is your browser

This is explained in the AWS ElasticsearchService [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-kibana.html):

> Because Kibana is a JavaScript application, requests originate from the user's IP address.

---

In terms of your next step, the answers to the following question cover the two options you have:

[How to access Kibana from Amazon elasticsearch service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751580/how-to-access-kibana-from-amazon-elasticsearch-service)

1. (Yaml solution, overall NOT advisable for several reasons) Add an extra statement to your access policy to allow actions from your device's IP address(es)
2. (Non-Yaml solution) Set up a proxy that will handle the requests from your browser and basically pass them on after signing them with the credentials of a trusted principal. This can either be a proxy running on additional AWS infrastructure or something running on your local machine. Again, the answers on the linked question go into more details.