# How get key field from amazon sqs queue?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, amazon-sqs

is this a good way to get bucket name and key name from amazon sqs queue

```
      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> messageMap = mapper.readValue(message, Map.class);
    ArrayList records = (ArrayList) messageMap.get("Records");
    LinkedHashMap firstRec = (LinkedHashMap) records.get(0);
    LinkedHashMap s3 = (LinkedHashMap) firstRec.get("s3");
    LinkedHashMap object = (LinkedHashMap) s3.get("object");
    String keyName = (String) object.get("key");//the actual object that's been uploaded
    LinkedHashMap bucket = (LinkedHashMap) s3.get("bucket");
    String name = (String) bucket.get("name");//the bucket name
```

Comment: How was the message sent to the Amazon SQS queue? Did it come from an Amazon S3 trigger?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example from [AWS S3 Event notification using Lambda function in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41261955/174777):

```java
public Object handleRequest(S3Event input, Context context) {
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());        

for (S3EventNotificationRecord record : input.getRecords()) {
    String s3Key = record.getS3().getObject().getKey();
    String s3Bucket = record.getS3().getBucket().getName();

    // retrieve s3 object
    S3Object object = s3Client.getObject(new GetObjectRequest(s3Bucket, s3Key));
    InputStream objectData = object.getObjectContent();

    ...
}        
return "success";}
```