# aws java: parse S3Put event coming from SQS to lambda

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-java-sdk

It's been a surprise for me to see that handle event sources is something handcrafty...

I mean, I've been strugling for some days to try to receive ("deserialize") an `S3Put` event into my handler (using spring-cloud-function-aws-adapter Consumer).

Currently, I'm using an `S3(send put event) -> SQS(send SQSMessage) -> lambda(receive SQSMessage)`.

My current code Lambda function (handler) is:

```java
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class PushedDocumentLambdaConsumer implements Function<SQSEvent, String> {

    @Override
    public String apply(SQSEvent sqsEvent) {
        log.info("Found " + sqsEvent.getRecords().size() + " sqs event(s)");
        for (SQSEvent.SQSMessage sqsMessage : sqsEvent.getRecords()) {
            log.info("sqs message body: {}", sqsMessage.getBody());

            final String body = sqsMessage.getBody().replace("Records", "records");
            log.info("Replaced sqs message body: {}", body);

            Gson gson = new Gson();
            S3Event s3Event = gson.fromJson(sqsMessage.getBody(), S3Event.class);
            log.info("s3Event.toString(): {}", s3Event.toString());

            if (s3Event != null && s3Event.getRecords() != null) {
                log.info("Number of records: {}", s3Event.getRecords().size());
                for (S3EventNotificationRecord s3EventNotificationRecord : s3Event.getRecords()) {
                    log.info("event name: {}", s3EventNotificationRecord.getEventName());
                    log.info("event source: {}", s3EventNotificationRecord.getEventSource());

                    S3Entity s3Entity = s3EventNotificationRecord.getS3();
                    if (null != s3Entity) {
                        log.info("s3Entity bucket name: {}", s3Entity.getBucket().getName());
                        log.info("s3Entity object name: {}", s3Entity.getObject().getKey());
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return "Ok";
    }

}
```

What I'm currently receiving is:

```json
{
   "Records":[
      {
         "body":"{\"Records\": [{\"eventVersion\": \"2.1\", \"eventSource\": \"aws:s3\", \"awsRegion\": \"us-east-1\", \"eventTime\": \"2024-03-01T12:54:12.608Z\", \"eventName\": \"ObjectCreated:Put\", \"userIdentity\": {\"principalId\": \"AIDAJDPLRKLG7UEXAMPLE\"}, \"requestParameters\": {\"sourceIPAddress\": \"127.0.0.1\"}, \"responseElements\": {\"x-amz-request-id\": \"b0c98e62\", \"x-amz-id-2\": \"eftixk72aD6Ap51TnqcoF8eFidJG9Z/2\"}, \"s3\": {\"s3SchemaVersion\": \"1.0\", \"configurationId\": \"abdde1c9\", \"bucket\": {\"name\": \"espaidoc\", \"ownerIdentity\": {\"principalId\": \"A3NL1KOZZKExample\"}, \"arn\": \"arn:aws:s3:::espaidoc\"}, \"object\": {\"key\": \"580d1374-2ec1-4bb3-8c14-2c43d07c7833\", \"sequencer\": \"0055AED6DCD90281E5\", \"size\": 2333, \"eTag\": \"1d11469e9d81f07729548d7708bbab82\"}}}]}",
         "receiptHandle":"ZGJhNTJjNDItODU1Yy00ZjY2LWI4MmUtY2RmNDRhNzg5YTRkIGFybjphd3M6c3FzOnVzLWVhc3QtMTowMDAwMDAwMDAwMDA6U3FzUXVldWVDcmVhdGUgMmI1YjY3OTctMjY0Yy00NTVlLTgyNzMtZDIwMDlkYWVhZDliIDE3MDkyOTc2NTMuNDg2MTU4",
         "md5OfBody":"2bb9d9a1a018099143bd02c0aea8b0cd",
         "eventSourceARN":"arn:aws:sqs:us-east-1:000000000000:SqsQueueCreate",
         "eventSource":"aws:sqs",
         "awsRegion":"us-east-1",
         "messageId":"2b5b6797-264c-455e-8273-d2009daead9b",
         "attributes":{
            "SenderId":"000000000000",
            "SentTimestamp":"1709297652665",
            "ApproximateReceiveCount":"1",
            "ApproximateFirstReceiveTimestamp":"1709297653486"
         },
         "messageAttributes":{
            
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to deserialize body to an S3Event using `Gson`, but I've realized that it gets me an S3Event without Records...

1. Is not there any library engaging for this parsing issues?
2. How could I parse it "manually"?

Comment: The JSON body you've shown has a `Records` array. Are you saying that the deserialized `s3Event` in your code has a null `Records` attribute or an empty/null return value when calling the `getRecords()` accessor? Also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41235593/aws-s3-event-notification-using-lambda-function-in-java).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is you're trying to use gson to parse the SQS message into an `S3Event`, when it is actually an [`S3EventNotification`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/event/S3EventNotification.html). It looks like you might not even have to parse it with gson, you could do this:

```
S3EventNotification s3EventNotification = S3EventNotification.parse(sqsMessage.getBody());
for (S3EventNotification.S3EventNotificationRecord record : s3EventNotification.getRecords())
{
    S3EventNotification.S3Entity s3Entity = record.getS3();
    if (null != s3Entity)
    {
        log.info("s3Entity bucket name: {}", s3Entity.getBucket().getName());
        log.info("s3Entity object name: {}", s3Entity.getObject().getKey());
    }
}
```