# How to create an Elasticsearch cluster using Amazon EC2 computers?

Tags: elasticsearch, amazon-ec2

I have two computers running in Amazon EC2. I want to setup an Elasticsearch cluster between them. I have installed the EC2 Discovery Plugin and also I have included Zen Discovery configuration in their YMLs. Despite these, the cluster is not being formed. Both are starting as independent nodes.

My network and discovery settings are:

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 8200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.1.2", "10.0.3.4"]
cloud.aws.access_key: "abc"
cloud.aws.secret_key: "xyz"
```

What other steps should I take to start the cluster?

Comment: Can you show the network configuration of both of your nodes?

Comment: I remember that you need to set on amazon machine level permissions for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978026/proper-access-policy-for-amazon-elastic-search-cluster

Comment: @Val I have added my cluster stats.

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat I will try that and let you know. How do I see my EC2 access policy?

Comment: That's not what I meant. We need to see the `network.*` and `discovery.*` settings in your `elasticsearch.yml` files.

Comment: @Val Updated the question

Comment: On both hosts you have the same config?

Comment: @Val Yes, on both of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hosts are not seeing each other because your `network.host` setting doesn't use the correct IP address:

On host1 you need this config:

```
network.host: 10.0.1.2
http.port: 8200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.3.4"]
cloud.aws.access_key: "abc"
cloud.aws.secret_key: "xyz"
```

On host2 you need this config:

```
network.host: 10.0.3.4
http.port: 8200
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["10.0.1.2"]
cloud.aws.access_key: "abc"
cloud.aws.secret_key: "xyz"
```

To simplify you can also have both hosts in the `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`, that will simplify automated deployments, but the above should work.

Comment: I shall do this tomorrow and let you know.

Will this allow me to run curl commands to these servers from outside the EC2?

Comment: 10.* are private IP addresses, so unless you have an SSH tunnel from your local host to a host inside your EC2 environment, no you won't be able to. But it's a [good idea](https://www.elastic.co/blog/protecting-against-attacks-that-hold-your-data-for-ransom) to bind to a private IP address in order to prevent outside attackers from reaching your cluster.

Comment: I have a DNS names for them. Can I use them in `network.host` and `discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts`?

Comment: Yes, you can use them.

Comment: You might also need to open the internal ports (probably 9300, unless you changed that) to each other with security groups. You should also probably set `discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 2` so you don't get a split brain.

Comment: @Val I'm getting a `BindTransportException[Failed to bind to [9300-9400]]; nested: BindException[Cannot assign requested address]`. I have opened ports from 9000-9500.

Comment: @Val I had used my hostname as `network.host`. When I changed it back to `0.0.0.0` or commented it, it started normally. But then the cluster was not formed.