# Configure AWS Sigv4 Authentication for Amazon ElasticSearch Service for Fluentbit

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, fluent-bit

I have AWS EKS and AWS ES running. I deployed Fluentbit as a Daemonset in EKS and now I want to enable AWS Sigv4 authentication to allow Fluentbit to send logs to the ES cluster. As far as I understand, I need to create an IAM role and provide Fluentbit with `AWS_Role_ARN` and `AWS_External_ID`.

[image]

How do I create a valid IAM role and policy to let Fluentbit securely communicate with the ES cluster?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Proper access policy for Amazon Elastic Search Cluster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32978026/proper-access-policy-for-amazon-elastic-search-cluster)

Comment: @jordanm I've tried to set up IAM role that way, but it doesn't work. I'm afraid there's something Fluentbit-specific that I'm missing.